# align-items: stretch and align-self: stretch don't work in flex row without fixed height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to add a vertical rule in a flex row whose height is not fixed (it is sized to fit its other contents).

I would like for the vertical rule to stretch the full height of the container (excluding the padding). I have tried `align-items: stretch` on the flex row, `align-self: stretch` on the vertical rule div, and `height: 100%` on the vertical rule div, but no matter what I do, the vertical rule only ever seems to have a height of 0px:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: orange;
  width: max-content;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
  height: max-content;
}

.vr {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 80px;
  width: 50px;
}

.lightblue {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 80px;
  width: 50px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 120px;
  width: 50px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 120px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="vr"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="purple"></div>
  <div class="vr"></div>
  <div class="lightblue"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any way that I can have my `.vr` div stretch to the full height of the container without giving the container a fixed height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the `height: 100%` from the `.vr` rules did the trick for me.